# Radio Button with image as an option instead of text

Tags: android

How can i add radio buttons in android app with option as an image , not the text.. we can set the text to radio button by android:setText property. But i want an image to be displayed there and not the text.. Please help me?

Comment: If you want to dynamically to do it means, You can use use @Anu answer. And, in your java file. Just find the `ImageView` with their id and Use the imagesource for that.

Comment: thanku very much.. i will try this now. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly putting RadioButton into LinearLayout causes that RadioGroup will stop managing checked states of nested buttons. Therefore the RadioGroup is useless now. Consider using <RadioButton android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"> This avoids need for LinearLayout and RadioGroup can do its job in managing nested RadioButtons.

Comment: @petrsyn Just got hit with this issue. The drawable method works fine except for the size of the drawable.

Comment: you can mange drawable size manually in drawable file

Comment: This solution will not work at all, it causes multiple radio buttons to be selectable and they cannot be unselected.

Comment: I don't know why people keep suggesting this kind of solution when talking about radio button

Answer (score 42):

How about this one using the property `android:drawableRight`?

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/maptype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/map" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/satellite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/sat" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: what if the images are sync from web/url ?

Comment: image size must fit, if a larger image is used as drawableRight of radio button it's not fit