# Using image in RadioButton instead of text

Tags: android, radio-button

[image: check image]

[image: check text]

In `Android`, I want to use `RadioButton`, but I do not want to check a plain text. How can I get the display in the first image instead of the second image? Using `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton`.

Comment: If images are not support by Android SDKs then do it the hard way. Do not provide any text to the radio button instead place an `ImageView` just next to the `RadioButton` inside a horizontal `LinearLayout`. For the `ImageView` provide a `onClickListener` that toggles the state of the `RadioButton`

Comment: Is this the only way? Looks a bit complicated....

Comment: I've just found a similar question to yours, they have provided examples, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081919/radio-button-with-image-as-an-option-instead-of-text

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing special to do.. just add drawable in it like this:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

For an effect like this:

[image]

`RadioButton` itself contains a `TextView` as default.. so you can do all the operations those are present for any `TextView`.

**BONUS**: If you want to change the circular dot that shows `check` status, just update the `android:button` tag to refer your own `drawable`.

Comment: How to wrap the `drawable` image's size? Some image will mess up the GUI when using the `wrap_content`, and will not wrap into the size, if you set the size into a value by yourself.

Comment: As said if allowed in `TextView`.. it can be done in `RadioButton` as well.. Please do a search for this one as this is something different than actual question..

Comment: Try "http://stackoverflow.com/a/12767817/3485152", if it doesn't work try making custom `RadioButton` and before drawable is placed scale it according to the height of your `RadioButton`... Also, be reasonable and search for answers before asking, you cannot bargain like this.

Comment: "drawableLeft image's size and I will accept your answer.."
hello @AnkitBansal is right he or anyone here are not answering question because of accept answer or something related to point. we are just share over experience with others

Answer (score 3):

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
```

this is the alteranative approch which i am using :-).

Comment: Using the same , but radio group does not work, I can select all radios while only one should be selected. If we load this layout in adapter, we are creating `RadioGroup` for each `RadioButton` which is the problem i see